# What's the Golang's equivalent of Ruby's "methods" method?

Tags: ruby, methods, go, reflection

I'm playing with Golang and I want to know if there is a way that can list all the methods or properties I can use on a variable. In Ruby I can simply use `some_variable.methods` to get all the methods defined on `some_variable`. Is there a similar thing in Golang?

Comment: Well, you tagged the question with "reflection" so you seem to know where to look: `package reflect`. Especially https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Method .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. With reflection, each `reflect.Type` object can enumerate all the methods the actual type exposes. but it's not a very common or idiomatic thing to do in Go:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
}

func (f Foo) Bar() {
}

func (f Foo) Baz() {
}

func main() {

    t := reflect.TypeOf(Foo{})
    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(t.Method(i).Name)
    }
}
// Output:
// Bar
// Baz
```

This can also be done on `reflect.Value`, depending on what you need.

But the real question is - what are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to check if a type implements an interface or something like this? There probably is a simpler solution to your goal. What is your actual goal?

Comment: Thank you. I just want to quickly take a look of all the methods or properties that I can use on a variable as I'm currently learning Golang.

Comment: @user130268 The documentation of the standard library is a better solution IMHO :)

Answer (score 2):

If you only need this in development phase [guru](http://golang.org/s/using-guru) development tool can help you a lot.